# Android Kotlin Coroutines: what is the difference between flow, callbackFlow, channelFlow,... other flow constructors

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have code that should change SharedPreferences into obsarvable storage with flow so I've code like this

```
internal val onKeyValueChange: Flow<String> = channelFlow {
        val callback = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, key ->
            coroutineScope.launch {
                //send(key)
                offer(key)
            }
        }

        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)

        awaitClose {
            sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)
        }
    }
```

or this

```
internal val onKeyValueChange: Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
        val callback = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, key ->
            coroutineScope.launch {
                send(key)
                //offer(key)
            }
        }

        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)

        awaitClose {
            sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(callback)
        }
    }
```

Then I observe this preferences for token, userId, companyId and then log into but there is odd thing as I need to build app three times like changing token not causes tokenFlow to emit anything, then second time new userId not causes userIdFlow to emit anything, then after 3rd login I can logout/login and it works. On logout I am clearing all 3 properties stores in prefs token, userId, companyId.

Answer (score 43):

For `callbackFlow`:

You cannot use `emit()` as the simple `Flow` (because it's a `suspend` function) inside a callback. Therefore the `callbackFlow` offers you a synchronized way to do it with the `trySend()` option.

Example:

```
fun observeData() = flow {
 myAwesomeInterface.addListener{ result ->
   emit(result) // NOT ALLOWED
 }
}
```

So, coroutines offer you the option of `callbackFlow`:

```
fun observeData() = callbackFlow {
 myAwesomeInterface.addListener{ result ->
   trySend(result) // ALLOWED
 }
 awaitClose{ myAwesomeInterface.removeListener() }
}
```

For `channelFlow`:

The main difference with it and the basic `Flow` is described in the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html):

> A channel with the default buffer size is used. Use the buffer
> operator on the resulting flow to specify a user-defined value and to
> control what happens when data is produced faster than consumed, i.e.
> to control the back-pressure behavior.

The `trySend()` still stands for the same thing. It's just a synchronized way (a non `suspending` way) for `emit()` or `send()`

I suggest you to check Romans Elizarov [blog](https://medium.com/@elizarov) for more detailed information especially [this](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf) post.

Regarding your code, for `callbackFlow` you wont' be needing a coroutine launch:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
                send(key)
                //trySend(key)
            }
```

Just use `trySend()`

Comment: `callbackFlow` started out as nothing but a synonym for `channelFlow`, on the current master the only difference is a minor specialization of `collectTo`. The return type is still `ChannelFlow` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you. You can edit the question btw. I thought `channelFlow` was actually a `flow{}.buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED)` but I wasn't so sure about it

Comment: Not sure in what way you mean I should edit OP's question. Can you clarify?

Comment: No I mean you can improve my answer sorry. Not question, answer

Comment: Which one is better to use?

Comment: `trySend()` is not just a synchronous, drop-in replacement for `send()`. It may fail if the flow's `SendChannel` is full. It's important to check the return value to make sure sent values aren't dropped.

Answer (score 1):

**Another Example, maybe much concrete:**

```
private fun test() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            someFlow().collectLatest {
                Log.d("TAG", "Finally we received the result: $it")
                // Cancel this listener, so it will not be subscribed anymore to the callbackFlow. awaitClose() will be triggered.
                // cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Define a callbackFlow.
     */
    private fun someFlow() = callbackFlow {

        // A dummy class which will run some business logic and which will sent result back to listeners through ApiCallback methods.
        val service = ServiceTest() // a REST API class for example

        // A simple callback interface which will be called from ServiceTest
        val callback = object : ApiCallback {
            override fun someApiMethod(data: String) {
                // Sending method used by callbackFlow. Into a Flow we have emit(...) or for a ChannelFlow we have send(...)
                trySend(data)
            }

            override fun anotherApiMethod(data: String) {
                // Sending method used by callbackFlow. Into a Flow we have emit(...) or for a ChannelFlow we have send(...)
                trySend(data)
            }
        }

        // Register the ApiCallback for later usage by ServiceTest
        service.register(callback)

        // Dummy sample usage of callback flow.
        service.execute(1)
        service.execute(2)
        service.execute(3)
        service.execute(4)

        // When a listener subscribed through .collectLatest {} is calling cancel() the awaitClose will get executed.
        awaitClose {
            service.unregister()
        }
    }

    interface ApiCallback {
        fun someApiMethod(data: String)
        fun anotherApiMethod(data: String)
    }

    class ServiceTest {

        private var callback: ApiCallback? = null

        fun unregister() {
            callback = null
            Log.d("TAG", "Unregister the callback in the service class")
        }

        fun register(callback: ApiCallback) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Register the callback in the service class")
            this.callback = callback
        }

        fun execute(value: Int) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                if (value < 2) {
                    callback?.someApiMethod("message sent through someApiMethod: $value.")
                } else {
                    callback?.anotherApiMethod("message sent through anotherApiMethod: $value.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```