# Is Kotlin's channelFlow a superset of flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutine-channel

We know that `channelFlow` can do what `flow` can't e.g.

- [Retrieve value from a concurrently run coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407831/3286489)
- [Can use a non-suspending way i.e. `trySend` to send data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865907/3286489)

It looks like it is more powerful than `flow`. I wonder

- if there's anything where `flow` can do but not in `channelFlow`, or
- if there's anything `flow` is preferred over `channelFlow` (e.g. in terms of efficiency or performance?)?

The reason I ask is, I want to see if we can just use `channelFlow` for everything instead, or what's the scenario we should use `flow` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an authoritative source, but there are two things I notice by browsing the documentation and source code.

1. `flow` is lighter-weight since it doesn't have the thread-safety features of a Channel.
2. `channelFlow` is buffered, but you can modify the buffer or make it `RENDEVOUS` with the `buffer()` operator. `flow` is not buffered, but you can use the `buffer()` operator, which wraps it in a Channel-based flow.

Personally, `flow` is my default choice for simplicity, unless the features of a Channel are needed. Frequently my cold flows are shared into a SharedFlow somewhere downstream, so I tend to avoid messing with buffering in the upstream. It all depends on where buffering behavior is best encapsulated on a case-by-case basis, though.

Comment: channelFlow with RENDEVOUS is different from the default behavior of flow, as per [explained here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/kotlins-channel-flow-with-rendezvous-is-not-the-same-as-kotlin-flow-dfb5cff235d5?sk=dded3228c0975521024c0ce558980175)

Comment: Interesting analysis. I suppose the extra layer of a channel that the flow is passing through moves up by one where suspension takes place in the queue. `.buffer()` on a regular flow adds a channel to it.